# Conditional type based on previous param value

Tags: typescript

I have the following example method written in TypeScript where I want to type check the passed params and prevent someone from passing in invalid values, but the second param needs to be differently type checked based on the first param value.

```
type Param1Type = "Morning" | "Afternoon" | "Evening";

type MorningType = "test1" | "test2" | "test3";
type AfternoonType = "example1" | "example2" | "example3";
type EveningType = "value1" | "value2" | "value3";

export const TEST = (param1: Param1Type, param2: MorningType) => {...
```

So I want to make this part: `param2: MorningType` dependant on the `param1` value. So if param1 is `Afternoon` it should type check param2 against `AfternoonType` and so on.

Could generics perhaps solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to solve if you can provide a mapping between `Param1Type` and the other types.

```
type Mapping = {
  "Morning": MorningType
  "Afternoon": AfternoonType
  "Evening": EveningType
}

export const TEST = <
  P1 extends keyof Mapping, 
  P2 extends Mapping[P1]
>(param1: P1, param2: P2) => {}
```

We add the two generic types `P1` and `P2` for both parameters. `P1` has to be a key of `Mapping` while `P2` is constrained to `Mapping[P1]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=32&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwIwBVzQLxQEQCyA9ggHYCWpA5nlAD74CCAZsBGUUabQ3gKIA3CBWp4A3ACgJoSFGJlKVTLNx42AZ2Coe%20DcABMOtRE0BmcdKxQWbDl2U58EAB4owAGwjb6T18g8Qhj54Lm6e5pIy0ILCig5QqgJw7gCuXkZJqYEZyWkRUlFycGBgiglQAN4SUPjyIjQAXHIk9Q7VTKzspJzcTTZdPW01-EL1eE0xrVgSAL5SLmAkwFAAxlyaUOh8AMro5QA87TCoUC5spAAm6lAA1hAgRMxFJYoANFBH%20qfO51fPpdQANrHAC6EgAfAAKMCIFCoJrHd4wpDIfQI-QASgS4MqcwkW12kLw-Ts3HeIT8AUMGPxO3QRLqijw5L02hpBPpI1ionJcAARis8BigA)

Comment: Yeah this looks great. I was thinking of doing a mapping but didn't know about the keyof with the extends via generics. Thanks!